# Where I can find all Bulma icon names?

Tags: bulma

I look through the [Bulma document page](http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/), but can't find icon name list. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulma uses Font Awesome icons as mentioned in documentation and you can find the list of all available icons at: [*fontawesome.io/icons*](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

Comment: Thanks. I read somewhere it uses two set of icons. One of them starts with fa in naming. The cheap sheet is handy http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

dont mean to dig up this old thread. one nice thing about recent versions of the bulma css framework is that there is no specific type of icon set that you have to use. it has the flexibility through `<span class="icon"></span>` or `<span class="icon-text"><span class="icon"></span></span>` which allow the flexibility of using material design icons, font awesome, ionicons, or iconify.design icons (which is actually a big repo of all sets). in the provided documentation and examples, fontawesome is used often, but in my opinion the attention to detail and consistency with font awesome icons make it a better choice (for me personally). also, with older versions of font awesome it was required to use the class fa-fw (for fixed-width consistency).. that is no longer required with newver versions (FontAwesome v6+ if I recall correctly).

Cheers, hope this helps with any additional confusion since I inadvertently found this after searching for something else.